# UnicodeDecodeError in mac with python3 when reading .txt files

Tags: python, python-3.x

I write some files as .txt with python3.6 in mac. And then, when I try to read them using:

```
f = open(...,'r')
lines = f.readlines()
```

I got this error:

> UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xe8 in position 10: invalid continuation byte

Can anyone help? 
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

How do you create file in python? Can you please show full example of your code? I am also working on Mac, but no issues. Please see one of simple examples below on how it works:

create file:

```
file = open('test9.txt', 'w')
file.write('first \n second line \n aaa')
file.close()
```

read file:

```
with open('test9.txt') as f:
    lines = f.readlines()
    print(lines)
```

created file is a plain text document with .txt

Comment: Thank you for help. My writing code is:                                                                    f = open(moving_train+file_name,'w',encoding = 'utf-8')
        for i in range(len(data)):
            f.write(data[i])
        f.close()                                                                                                         where moving_train and filename is string, and data is a list of strings           and for reading these files, the code is  f = open(train_y+name,'r')
        lines = f.readlines()
        f.close()